# Python3 SMTP ValueError: server_hostname cannot be an empty string or start with a leading dot

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib

```
import smtplib
smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
smtp.connect('smtp.gmail.com','587')
(220, b'smtp.gmail.com ESMTP h15-v6sm187291iog.48 - gsmtp')
smtp.starttls()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 771, in starttls
    server_hostname=self._host)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 843, in _create
    owner=self, session=self._session,
ValueError: server_hostname cannot be an empty string or start with a leading dot.
```

I am using python 3.7 on Mac and cannot perform a tls handshake with gmail. This code works on python 2.7, and on my Ubuntu server using python 3.5.2. Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 33):

It seems a python3.7 [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/44552), pass the hostname to smtplib.SMTP will fix it

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
smtp.connect('smtp.gmail.com','587')
```

Comment: The problem also appears in SMTP_SSL: https://bugs.python.org/issue36094
Since Python 3.7 the problem is present and the workaround is the mentioned patch by @tao zhang

Comment: If have the bug also in python 3.5. Is there already an issue about that?

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with the previous solution, as I also wanted to set the debug level to get some more information and bypassed it by setting the `_host` of the `smtp` instance:

```python
MAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
smtp._host = MAIL_HOST
smtp.set_debuglevel(100) # just for demo purpose
smtp.connect(MAIL_HOST, 587)
```

Comment: good workaround until this issue is resolved, https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/80275