# TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out (starttls())

Tags: python

I was having previously an issue where I was getting `ValueError: server_hostname cannot be an empty string or start with a leading dot`. Checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768041/python3-smtp-valueerror-server-hostname-cannot-be-an-empty-string-or-start-with) in Stack Overflow and when I followed the instruction and run in the console:

```
import smtplib

smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com').connect(host='gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', port=25)
```

but I am getting a time-out as per below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 1034, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 253, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 1040, in _get_socket
    new_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
```

I get the issue **only** when I enable in my code `server.starttls()`. If this is commented out, it can send email fine.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL()
server.connect('gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', 25) # mail server  want to connect to.
server.set_debuglevel(True) # shows communication with the server in the console
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
```

Comment: The bug might be in 3.8 as well, why don't you try what they said in the other post?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 SMTP ValueError: server\_hostname cannot be an empty string or start with a leading dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768041/python3-smtp-valueerror-server-hostname-cannot-be-an-empty-string-or-start-with)

Comment: I tried the suggestion in the other post but it didn't work for me. Still get same error

Comment: Your code above doesn't show that. So how can we help? Post a [mre]

Comment: @Tomerikoo `server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host = 'smtp.gmail.com').connect(host ='smtp.gmail.com',port = 465) # mail server we want to connect to.
server.set_debuglevel(True) # shows communication with the server in the console
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()`  it hangs and doesn't send the email, whereas previously it was throwing an error - i have also tried `import smtplib;smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='smtp.gmail.com').connect(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=465)` in the console and same behaviour, it hangs

Comment: Please [edit] your question. This is not readable. Have a look at [ask] and how to provide a [mre]

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks - i have done it. Excuse my ignorance i am  new the platform

Answer (score -3):

maybe you could try using python 3.9. I dont know what operating system youre using but if youre using mac you have to use pip3 instead of pip so python can understand it (mac has python 2 as default) Hope i could help :)

Comment: If you have a problem, you don't change the entire programming language you are working on, you try to fix it.

Comment: What difference will that make? Do you have some proof/source that the bug was fixed in 3.9?

Comment: no it was an idea and, i dont have proof but i was just trying to be helpful